# no output with \usepackage{emp}

Tags: packages, compiling, metapost, output, emp

I'm trying to embed MetaPost graphics inside a LaTeX file using the [`emp`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/emp) package, with pdflatex.

When I include the line:

```
\usepackage{emp} %part 1
```

pdflatex doesn't produce any output (it says 0 pages), but doesn't seem to create an error.

I've checked that it works without that line, and I've checked that `emp` is installed. I've tried reinstalling MiKTeX, which someone said worked on a similar problem. I haven't even included any MetaPost yet. I've tried it with the lines suggested at this page (which I've divided into part 2 and part 3:

http://www.cs.bgu.ac.il/~gwiener/software-engineering/how-to-embed-uml-in-latex/

And I've tried it without. The only way it will give output is if I don't include any of that stuff. If part 1 is there, it just doesn't work.

Am I being a complete moron?

Attached is a MWE.

```
\documentclass{article}

%part 1:
\usepackage{emp}

%part 2:
\ifx\pdftexversion\undefined
\usepackage[dvips]{graphicx}
\else
\usepackage[pdftex]{graphicx}
\DeclareGraphicsRule{*}{mps}{*}{}
\fi

\begin{document}
\begin{empfile} %part 3
\begin{empcmds} %part 3
input metauml;  %part 3
\end{empcmds}   %part 3
\section{What is a set?}
A set is a collection of objects.
\end{empfile}   %part 3
\end{document}
```

Comment: You have to run Metapost on the resulting `.mp` file and run LaTeX again; but you have no `emp` environment in the example. Can you add one? However, I get one page.

Comment: The `\ifx\pdftexversion\undefined` in your example is wrong in a modern system. `\pdftexversion` is always defined, even if you run `latex`. Use the `ifpdf` package for such tests.

Comment: Following @UlrikeFischer's remark: Your whole section with `\ifx\pdftexversion\undefined` is not needed: Just load `graphicx` without an explicit driver and it will pick the right one.